# Header moves on different web pages

Tags: html, css

Hi I just set up a website  and I placed some other webpage inside to check what looks like. When looking at webpages, on 2 of the pages the  moves to the right for some reason. Just wondering if anyone had any thoughts why the heading is moving only on these 2 pages and not the other 2.

If you wanted to view my problem its on ***teamnews.org*** if you click on "tours" then on "about" the header moves to the right slightly on "about" page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop browser from resizing website when scrollbar is visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765636/stop-browser-from-resizing-website-when-scrollbar-is-visible)

Comment: This is the expected behaviour as vertical scroll-bar becomes visible. 

Well - I gone through your website - http://teamnews.org. I think you have developed this in plain HTML - you may always try with advanced CMSs such as DRUPAL so you wont have worry too much about the base-setup of the website.

Comment: @PralhadNarsinhSonar Your suggestion on a CMS is unrelated to the issue at hand.

Comment: @christopher-marshall - First line of the comment is related to the question. From my point of view even suggestion of CMS is related too - which might help him to get the website development much faster. Just take it easy. :)

Comment: Thanks for help everyone and @patricksweeney if you think it's to easy for  you just don't answer it, just ignore the question and take a day off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of your scroll bar on the right side. Add this to the first two pages.

```
body{
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```